# Automate switch user password in script

Tags: server

I have to write a script and it requires root privileges to execute some linux commnads and to stop & start some services. I'm asked to disable sudo access totally for all the users (as the normal users can gain access to root with the command 'sudo -s') and I did it. So I'm looking for the script to automate the switch user password(su) which does not need user intervention.

**EDIT**:1

On further research I got following script what I'm in need of:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import pexpect
import os
passwd = "my-root-password-here"
child = pexpect.spawn('su root')
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline(passwd)
child.expect('$')
child.interact()
```

I have checked this script executing manually logging in as normal user and it switched to root without any problem. But when I type `exit/ctrl+d` to switch back to the normal user, I'm getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./su3.py", line 9, in <module>
  child.interact()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1492, in interact
  self.__interact_copy(escape_character, input_filter, output_filter)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1520, in __interact_copy
  data = self.__interact_read(self.child_fd)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pexpect.py", line 1510, in __interact_read
  return os.read(fd, 1000)
OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

any help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users cannot run `sudo -s` if they don't have permissions to run whatever the SHELL is.

What you want is to have your users tell you *exactly* what commands they want to be able to run. Be especially careful that any commands they want to run are *owned by root* so they can't replace them with something that elevates their privileges later.

If they want to be able to run `ifconfig` for instance,

```
%netadmins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig
```

Try that, and you'll see that the netadmins group can only run `/sbin/ifconfig` with no password entered as root.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge and it will be useful for many!

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run that script as a non-root user, you should configure `sudo` to allow that.  You can configure sudo per user or group to allow all or only certain commands, either with or without password.  Completely disabling sudo for all users is probably not what you want...

Comment: As the users can easily gain access to root simply entering their own password with the command 'sudo -s', I had to disable sudo completely. I have tried some scripts but that didn't work for me.

Comment: `sudo -s` only works if you allow it (e.g. on Ubuntu, it's allowed for all users that are members of the ‘admin’ group, but not for other users).  You should read the sudo & sudoers & visudo documentation to learn more about this.  I need some sleep before providing you examples though... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could set the execute sticky bit on that script so that it will always execute as the owner of the script.  Something like `chmod 4750 script_name`

[Expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) can be used to automate responses in a script.  Be careful with either of these as they can introduce security risks, especially when giving regular users elevated privileges.

Properly configuring sudo, instead of disabling it completely, as JanC stated, is probably the best solution.

Comment: Having assigned the sticky bit still says "You need root privileges to run this script". Yes, I'm looking for the expect script but I can't do myself as I'm poor at programming.

Comment: Is the script owned by root?  Setting the sticky bit as above will execute as the script owner.  There are many expect examples online.  Try [Expect Examples](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11583).

Comment: The "sticky" bit does not control what user an executable runs as. In normal files, it basically does nothing (it was an old unix trick to get a file to "stick" in RAM). On directories, it does cause the permissions to work a bit differently, so that even if you have write access, you can only rename and delete your own files. This is for temp directories.

Comment: What you probably meant was the setuid bit. This would work if his script were an actual binary executable, but this does not work on scripts.

Comment: -1 The setuid bit does not work for shell scripts

Comment: I didn't try `Expect` and I'm sure I'll try this definitely. Thank you very much for your interest and sharing your knowledge.